# GA Cross Domain Misconfiguration

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-analytics-firebase, conversion-tracking

I am tracking across 2 domains that share the UA tracking ID. I have set-up the code to track across the 2 domains, added both domains to the Referral Exclusion list, and tested this and it works.

However, I noted that all conversions are being attributed to Direct/Referral. So no conversions are recorded for Organic, AdWords (manual tagging is on and the goals have been imported into the AdWords account) etc.

I got onto GA support where I was told the reason that it's not working is because I added my domain to the referral exclusion list, which I thought was a required step.

So, based on their advice I removed the domains from the list. Now, the conversion attribution is still incorrect AND I am getting self-referrals.

Any ideas where else to look?

Comment: Adding your domains to the referral exclusion list is a required step. I would start by checking the page depth metric in the conversion reports - if the numbers there are very small this suggests that tracking is interrupted somewhere within your page and users get a new client id.  Is there a chance that we can look at your site ?

Comment: Thank you!! Google did come back and said the referral exclusion was correct (their mistake!). They've had one of the "technical experts" have another look and they said: "Cookie gets refreshed during the redirect. > Cannot see data in GA under current View." This doesn't make sense to me. Also, this isn't the only account that's doing this. I have another one that's cross domain tracking w/ ecommerce and the same exact thing is happening (different website and ecomm back-end). The site is greencrossvet.com.au

Comment: After spending a better part of the day in this, I may have a theory.... One sites cross domain uses a 302 from the click to the landing page - do we lose referrer information because of this? The second sites cross domain uses a POST method from the click to the landing page - this hides the referrer information? If this is true, what is a way to handle this so the referrer information makes it into Google Analytics?

Comment: Does the redirect pass along the _ga parameter ? You need to get the client id from one domain to the other, else GA will not be able to connect the sessions between the two domains.

Comment: How do I check that? Review the HTTP headers? If so, the cookie _ga= on the 1st site is different than the one specified on the xDomain

Comment: If you have different client ids this will not only be tracked as different sessions, but as different users (i.e. no cross domain tracking happens). You need to carry over the client id in the _ga parameter, either via the url so the client side analytics code on the other domain can read it, or via a serverside mechanism that reads a client id transmitted in the body of your post requests and passes it to the tracker on the other domain when the tracker instance is created.

Comment: Thanks! I see the _ga set at the URL, but perhaps this is being written over?

Comment: I think it's really impossible to tell without looking at your page (i.e. did you set the 'allowLinker' parameter on both domains, else the code will not piuck up the clientid etc). But basically yes, it seems the parameter that transfers the clientid and thus the session is lost somewhere.

Comment: Eike, thanks so much for your input, it's all very helpful. the 'allowLinker' is on both domains and is working as expected, as we are getting conversion data (via Direct). After testing this numerous times I believe the _ga paramter is lost on the redirect for the first, and never set in the 2nd instance due to the POST method. Google support is still looking into it. I'd imagine they'd come back with the same answer here.